# Jmeter - How do I know when the test is finished executing?

Tags: jmeter

Simple question, when the test is done executing, does the Start item in the Run menu become enabled again ? I see it disabled for a period while my test is running and then become enabled again. I ask because I've been running Jmeter for 3 days and don't see the tests completing but see start become re-enabled.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be an indicator at the right corner. When the execution is going on there will be green signal shown at this location when it gets completed the green notificatuion is not shown....

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've seen that seems to be a clear indicator  that tests have completed is that when you start a test by clicking  the green "Start" button, the button becomes grayed out, and looks disabled. It re-enables when the  tests have stopped.

So just look at the Play button's state for an  indicator of whether or not the test is still running.